# Compiling give : expected initializer before eSellerate_ValidateSerialNumber

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, initialization

I am trying to convert eSellerate example from c++ to QT, but I'm getting this error while compiling:

> expected initializer before eSellerate_ValidateSerialNumber

Does anybody know where is the mistake?

```
#ifndef _VALIDATE_API_H_
#define _VALIDATE_API_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
#endif

typedef char* eSellerate_String;
typedef short eSellerate_DaysSince2000;

eSellerate_DaysSince2000 __stdcall
eSellerate_ValidateSerialNumber (
  eSellerate_String serialNumber, /* 0-terminated ASCII string                    */
  eSellerate_String nameBasedKey, /* 0-terminated ASCII string (NULL if unneeded) */
  eSellerate_String extraDataKey, /* 0-terminated ASCII string (NULL if unneeded) */
  eSellerate_String publisherKey  /* 0-terminated ASCII string                    */
);
```

Comment: Are you compiling in Windows?

Comment: i gave up this long time ago, yes it was under windows